# In a .htaccess file, how to remove an HTTP response header only on a virtual folder?

Tags: .htaccess, http-headers, apache2.4

Let's say that I have an HTTP response header named "foo" to be included in every response of the website.

How could I remove this header when a user requests the `/bar` URL and every other request starting with this path?

Comment: "a header named "foo"" - what do you mean by this? What is a "header" in this context? How is this "header" being included?

Comment: It could be any header but in this case, I want to change Content-Secuirty-Policy and define new security policy rules under a certain virtual folder. The CSP is defined using a simple "Header set Content-Secuirty-Policy ..." in the .htaccess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to remove an HTTP response header that has already been set earlier in the `.htaccess` file, you can use mod_rewrite to conditionally set an environment variable on the URL-path and use this to conditionally remove (or `unset`) the HTTP response header.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Set REMOVE_HEADER env var depending on the URL-path
RewriteRule ^bar - [E=REMOVE_HEADER:1]

# Unset the "foo" header if the REMOVE_HEADER is set
Header unset foo env=REMOVE_HEADER
```